Save attachment of mail in specified folder: Run-time Error '-2147221233 (8004010f)'
The VBA code is for saving attachments from an Outlook mail.
Here is the error message I receive when I attempt to run it.

Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)'

Code:
Sub SaveOutlookAttachments()

    'This early-binding version requires a reference to the Outlook and Scripting Runtime object libraries
    
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim dir As Scripting.Folder
    Dim dirName As String
    
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Trinh Thu Ha")
    
    For Each i In fol.Items
    
        If i.Class = olMail Then
        
            Set mi = i
            
            If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                'Debug.Print mi.SenderName, mi.ReceivedTime, mi.Attachments.Count
                
                dirName = _
                    "F:\VAPCO\Outlook Mail Collection 2024\" & _
                    Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-nn-ss ") & _
                    Left(Replace(mi.Subject, ":", ""), 10)
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirName)
                End If
                
                For Each at In mi.Attachments
                    'Debug.Print vbTab, at.DisplayName, at.Size
                    at.SaveAsFile dir.Path & "\" & at.Filename   
                Next at
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

What can I try to resolve this?

Error is on which line?  What's the text of the error?

Try renaming this variable to something that is not also a VBA function. - Dim dir As Scripting.Folder

Set fol = ns.Folders(1)... is not reliable if there is more than one mailbox.
Option Explicit

Sub ReferenceMailbox()

    'This early-binding version requires a reference to the Outlook object library
    
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    
    Dim olFol As Outlook.folder
    Dim olFolName As String
    olFolName = "Trinh Thu Ha"
    
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim olStore As Outlook.Store
    Dim olStoreFol As Outlook.folder
    
    For j = 1 To Session.Stores.Count
    
        Set olStore = Session.Stores(j)
                
        If MsgBox("Is this the expected mailbox name?" & vbCr & vbCr & _
          olStore.DisplayName, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
          
            Set olStoreFol = Session.Folders(olStore.DisplayName)
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    If Not olStoreFol Is Nothing Then
    
        ' Folder at same level as Inbox.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olFol = olStoreFol.Folders(olFolName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If olFol Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Folder not found directly under: " & vbCr & vbCr & olStore.DisplayName
        End If
        
    Else
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub ReferenceInbox()

    'This early-binding version requires a reference to the Outlook object library
    
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    
    Dim olFol As Outlook.folder
    Dim olFolName As String
    olFolName = "Trinh Thu Ha"
    
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.folder

    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim olStore As Outlook.Store
    Dim olStoreFol As Outlook.folder
    
    For j = 1 To Session.Stores.Count
    
        Set olStore = Session.Stores(j)
                
        If MsgBox("Is this the expected mailbox name?" & vbCr & vbCr & _
          olStore.DisplayName, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
          
            Set olStoreFol = Session.Folders(olStore.DisplayName)
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
    Next

    If Not olStoreFol Is Nothing Then
    
        ' Folder one level under Inbox
        Set olInbox = olStoreFol.Folders("Inbox")
        
        ' Breaking up the folders simplifies debugging
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olFol = olInbox.Folders(olFolName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If olFol Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Folder not found directly under Inbox of: " & vbCr & vbCr & olStore.DisplayName
        End If
                    
    Else
        Exit Sub
    
    End If
    
End Sub


0x8004010F is MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND, which most likely (since you don't specify which line of your code is raising the exception) means the folder named "Trinh Thu Ha" does not exist in the store.
If you have more than store and assuming the folder is on the same level as your Inbox folder, change the line
Set fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Trinh Thu Ha")

to
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Trinh Thu Ha")

